# Is there anyway to inspect knockout observables using Chrome debugger?

Tags: knockout.js, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to inspect observables using the Chrome debugger. I am using the knockout plugin, but it isn't showing information on the observables I'm interested in. The workaround I've been using is to set the observable to the global window object and inspect it in the console. This is time consuming for several reasons.

Comment: Possibly https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en ?
See also https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/02/26/debugging-bindings-knockout-3-0/

Comment: What works really well for me: right click an HTML element and select _inspect element_, go to your dev tools console and type `ko.dataFor($0)` or `ko.contextFor($0)` (ko must be in window for this to work). The console will log your current binding data/context.

Comment: these observables are not bound to HTML elements

Comment: Can you see your viewmodel in the debugger?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Not all of my observables are associated with a viewmodel.

Comment: Also, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/knockout.js/5066/debugging-a-knockout-js-application/27325/printing-a-binding-context-from-markup#t=201702022123141358325

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the non-minified knockout library, you can inspect the `_latestValue` variable which is exposed on each non-computed observable. In the case of `computed`s, IIRC you can find an exposed `_latestValue` variable in the exposed `state` variable on the `computed`.

So to summarize, you can inspect the observables via these variables **if you're referencing the debug (aka. non-minified) build of `knockout`**.

```
var observable = ko.observable();
var computed = ko.computed(...);
...
observable._latestValue;
computed._state.latestValue;
```

EDIT: I've fixed the case for `computed`, but note, that if you're using the latest knockout (version >= 3.4.1), you can directly use `computed._latestValue` too, as it got exposed just as for an `observable`.

Comment: I had a mistake in the `computed` case, correctly it's `computed._state.latestValue` instead of `computed.state._latestValue`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem (and I may not, I don't generally use the debugger to inspect variables, I pepper my code with `console.debug` instead), you can't see the values in your observables because they're functions, and you can only inspect data values.

You could keep your values available by subscribing to the observables with a function that copies them. A convenient place would be attached to the observable itself. Just create a new kind of observable:

```
function debugObservable(value) {
    var self = ko.observable();

    self.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        self.internalValue = newValue;
    });
    self(value);
    return self;
}
```

When you want to inspect it, find the observable and look at its `internalValue` property.

Comment: Note that if you're using the non-minified `knockout` library, you can inspect the `_latestValue` variable which is defined on each `observable`, but not on `computed`s. On the latter you will find it inside `state` variable IIRC.